# Counting bits in a int - why does this code work?

Tags: c, binary, integer, bit

I was trying to learn more about bits, and I came across [this example](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).

How does this code work to count the bits?  (My C is very rusty, by the way).

```
unsigned int v; // count the number of bits set in v
unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v

for (c = 0; v; v >>= 1)
{
  c += v & 1;
}
```

Comment: This is not a code review platform. Please do that in the code review section. There are very good and more efficient solutions for counting bits in other questions, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`v & 1` is 1 if the lowest bit in `v` is set, and 0 if it's not.

The loop keeps dividing shifting the bits of `v`right by 1 place each iteration, and thus the lowest bit of `v` loops over each of the bits in the original `v` (as each one gets to the 1's place before "falling off" the fractional end).

Thus, it loops over each bit and adds 1 to c if it's set, and adds 0 if it's not, thus totaling the set bits in the original v.

For example, with a starting `v` of `1011`:

1. `1011 & 1 = 1`, so c is incremented to 1.
2. Then `1011` is shifted to become `101`.
3. `101 & 1 = 1`, so c is incremented to 2.
4. `101` is shifted to become `10`.
5. `10 & 1 = 0`, so c isn't incremented and remains 2.
6. `10` is shifted to become `1`.
7. `1 & 1 = 1`, so c is incremented to 3.
8. `1` is shifted to become `0` (because the last bit fell off the fractional end).
9. Since the condition of the `for` loop is just `v`, and v is now 0, which is a false value, the loop halts.

End result, c = 3, as we desire.

Comment: I like your answer the best :-)

Answer (score 2):

v >>= 1 will keep shifting the least significant bit off until v is all zeros.  so we Don't stop until we've counted them all.  v&1 tests if the bit we are about to shift off is a 1, so we make sure to count it before we shift it off.

Answer (score 1):

`v &` basically extracts the least significant bit of `v` -- it's `1` if that bit is set, `0` if not.  Every iteration through the loop it shifts `v` 1 place to the right.  And within each iteration, it adds the result of that `v &` test to a counter `c`.  So every bit that's set means `1` gets added; every clear bit `0` is added.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are comparing 1 bit of `v` to the value 1, and you know the truth table for AND.

- 1 & 0 = 0
- 0 & 1 = 0
- 1 & 1 = 1

So if the bit from `v` is 1, it will produce 1 if ANDed with 1. Then shift `v` by 1 bit and continue.